# Text being interfered when trying to center

Tags: jquery, html, css

Not exactly sure why's doing this but I am simply just trying to get my text horizontally and vertically centered inside it's parent div. I have viewed several SO answers on how to do this and have looked at the following examples

[1](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html) 
(I had 2 examples of SO answers but I don't have 10 rep yet and cannot post 2 links)

but for some reason it's just not working for me. [Live demo](http://jdmdev.net/parallax/classic.html) it's centering it horizontally but vertically I am getting a weird right-hug on the screen. I even tried doing this in jQuery (example below) and it's giving me the SAME right-hug as the 2 SO answers I found, so I know there must be some minor issue. Here's my HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<div
    class="parallax-image-wrapper parallax-image-wrapper-100"
    data-anchor-target="#dragons + .gap"
    data-bottom-top="transform:translate3d(0px, 200%, 0px)"
    data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px)">

    <div
        class="parallax-image parallax-image-100"
        style="background-image:url(images/pot.jpg)"
        data-anchor-target="#dragons + .gap"
        data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -80%, 0px);"
        data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 80%, 0px);"
    ></div>
    <!--the +/-80% translation can be adjusted to control the speed difference of the image-->

</div>

    <div class="gap gap-100">
        <h3 class="centerMe">Why waste edible food?</h3>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .centerMe
    {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            text-align: center;
    }
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).resize(function(){

         $('.centerMe').css({
          position:'absolute',
          left: ($(window).width() 
            - $('.gap gap-100').outerWidth())/2,
          top: ($(window).height() 
            - $('.gap gap-100').outerHeight())/2
         });

        });

        // To initially run the function:
        $(window).resize();

       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jquery on Resize solution, you forgot to substract your text div's width and also you need to divide by 2 the browser width to position your element dead center horizontally:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $(window).resize(function(){

     $('.centerMe').css({
      position:'absolute',
      left: (($(window).width() /2) - ($('.centerMe').width() / 2)),
      top: ($(window).height() 
        - $('.gap gap-100').outerHeight())/2
     });

    });

    // To initially run the function:
    $(window).resize();

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `CSS3` property to `.centerMe`

```
.centerMe{

    /*text-align:center;*/
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can absolute center just in css but you need to define a height and a width for the div you are trying to absolute center.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>Absolute center</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  display:table;
}

span{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/4536/